# Possible differences between two environments

Tags: database, magento-2.2.1

We've got production and staging Magento 2.2.1 setups located on the same server.
MySQL version is 5.7.20.
They basically use the same MySQL instance and the same data (of course copied and filtered from production to staging).

The problem is, when running this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON 
    cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND 
    cat_index.store_id='1' AND 
    cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND 
    cat_index.category_id='2'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON 
    price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND 
    price_index.website_id = '1' AND 
    price_index.customer_group_id = 0
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON 
    (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND 
    (at_qty.stock_id=1 and qty > 0)
INNER JOIN `catalogrule_product` ON 
    (catalogrule_product.product_id = e.entity_id) AND 
    (catalogrule_product.website_id='1' AND 
    catalogrule_product.customer_group_id=0)
INNER JOIN `catalogrule` ON catalogrule.rule_id = 
    catalogrule_product.rule_id and 
    from_date < '2017-11-17 23:59:59' and 
    to_date > '2017-11-17 00:00:00'
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON 
    e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND 
    stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND 
    stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 
WHERE 
    (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1);
```

Staging and production give pretty different results in terms of time. (250ms vs 1.1s) - these values are the average of 20 runs.

What I researched?

```
    mysql: show full processlist;
```

Not much was going on. Low traffic on production.

Now, my question is indeed why? What can there be different between these two environments?

Comment: May be possible reindex missing into staging server

Comment: Will reindex staging make it slower? I don't understand.

Comment: Cron is running on live server may be it will slow your server

Comment: As I explained in my question, staging and production are hosted on the same dedicated server. The only difference is staging is accessed through a subdomain. BTW: I updated the query.

Comment: As mentioned by @SunilPatel, I triend reindexing, but instead of doing so on staging, I did it on production. Guess what? It lowered the response time in production. SunilPatel: If this had been an answer, I'd accept it as being the correct one.

Comment: Make sure all index are valid..